# Responsive UI GridView layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

I have surveyed in other sites and got different responses about how I can solve my problem. In fact the problem is that I am trying to make a responsive gridView layout to display 25 textviews with numbers. I had hard time in constructing it the way I want but here is what I got:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context="com.example.hristodraganov.bingo.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="4">


</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="6"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"
    />
```

This is the layout that is used on the MainActivity. I inflate it with textview item with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#d3d3d3"
android:gravity="center">

<com.example.****.****.SquareView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/cell"
    android:textColor="#D0583B"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="30sp">

</com.example.****.****.SquareView>
```

There is the extension of the BaseAdapter class that is used to inflate the grid with the textviews:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final Context mContext;
    private  String[] numbers;


    public GridAdapter(Context context, String[] numbers) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numbers.length;
    }


    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View gridView;

        if (convertView == null) {

            gridView = new View(mContext);


            gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview_layout, null);


            TextView textView = (TextView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.cell);
            textView.setText(numbers[position]);

        } else {
            gridView = (View) convertView;
        }

        return gridView;
    }

}
```

Also, I am forcing the textView to be squared in this SquareView class:

```
public class SquareView extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView {

public SquareView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec); 
}}
```

The layout is doing fine by now, here is an image of the size I used to construct it [Nexus 5X](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H4k9l.jpg). It looks good but when I change to 4" -[Nexus S](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIVH6.jpg) the whole last row is somewhere below the screen. Also this happens to 5"-[Nexus 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fcN0.jpg) where the last row is slightly visible. Above 5.2" to 6.0" the layout fits perfectly. So my question is what should I do in this scenario to make the layout fit for small-sized screens without making a duplicate layout for them. (Note: I was told that the BaseAdapter implementation would fix the responsiveness of the layout). Any ideas what could I do? (Sorry for the long texts.)

Answer (score 0):

Because there are a lot of different Android devices out there your best choice would be to encapsulate your layout in a `ScrollView`.

Another option is to get rid of the weights and let the top `RelativeLayout` grow/shrink after the `GridView` has taken all the space it needs. This still might not work on smaller screens or in landscape.

```

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">


</RelativeLayout>

<GridView
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="70dp"
    android:numColumns="5"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
    android:stretchMode="spacingWidth"/>
```

```